# enum as an argument in C# function

Tags: c#, enums, void

I'm trying to write a program that writes text char by char. And I want to choose a write speed using enum. But it throws an error. So, this is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace WritingApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum WriteMode { Slow, SlowRandom, Normal, NormalRandom, Fast, FastRandom };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageWrite("smth", WriteMode.Fast); //Error here
//An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property   
//'Program.MessageWrite(string, Program.WriteMode)'
        }

        void MessageWrite(string message, WriteMode mode)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(message[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you see, I haven't used it in the function itself.

Comment: put `static` keyword before `void MessageWrite(stri...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `MessageWrite` static.

```
static void MessageWrite(string message, WriteMode mode)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(message[i]);
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Why static methods can't call non-static methods directly?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284088/why-static-methods-cant-call-non-static-methods-directly)